# How to avoid duplicates while doing unnest of multiple columns based on comma delimiter in bigquery?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, unnest

I am using below query to split the comma separated rows into 2 rows. But facing duplicate issues.

`SELECT colm_A,colm_B, colm_C From Db.Table_A, UNNEST(Split(COLM_B,',')), COLM_B, UNNEST(SPLIT(COLM_C,',')) COLM_C;`

Actual table

| Colm_A | Colm_B | Colm_C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Fish | F |
| 2 | Dog,cat | D,C |

Output from above query

| Colm_A | Colm_B | Colm_C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Fish | F |
| 2 | Dog | D |
| 2 | Cat | C |
| 2 | Dog | D |
| 2 | Cat | C |

Expected output

| Colm_A | Colm_B | Colm_C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Fish | F |
| 2 | Dog | D |
| 2 | Cat | C |

Answer (score 1):

Use below approach

```
select Colm_A, Colm_B, Colm_C
from your_table, 
unnest(split(Colm_B)) Colm_B with offset
join unnest(split(Colm_C)) Colm_C with offset
using (offset)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: As per your suggestion, the logic for 2 columns with comma delimiter works fine..but when i try to use the same logic with more than 2 columns, i am getting a error. I have included the logic that i used and the error that i got. can you please with this and let me know where i am wrong?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/78061765/5221944