# QUERY ERROR - Duplicate alias offset found

Tags: google-bigquery, unnest

I am trying to use the below logic to get the expected output, but getting error mentioned on my question,

I am trying to unnest multiple columns based on comma delimiter and to avoid duplicates while unnesting it and doing a join to avoid duplicates. when i join 2 columns with offset, i am not seeing any issues , but when doing with more than 2 columns, facing errors.

```
select Colm_A, Colm_B, Colm_C
from your_table, 
unnest(split(Colm_B)) Colm_B with offset
join unnest(split(Colm_C)) Colm_C with offset join unnest(split(Colm_D)) Colm_D
using (offset);
```

SOURCE TABLE

```
Colm_A  Colm_B  Colm_C COL_D
1       Fish     F      H
2       Dog,cat  D,C    G,T
```

Expected output

```
Colm_A  Colm_B  Colm_C  COLM_D
1       Fish    F        H
2        Dog    D        G
2        Cat    C        T
```

Comment: can anyone please help on this?

Answer (score 0):

Use below

```
select Colm_A, Colm_B, Colm_C, Colm_D
from your_table, 
unnest(split(Colm_B)) Colm_B with offset as B
join unnest(split(Colm_C)) Colm_C with offset as C on B = C
join unnest(split(Colm_D)) Colm_D with offset as D on B = D
```

with output

[image]

Comment: sorry for the trouble, I have few doubts. Let me edit the question in 5 minutes. Can you please help with this

Comment: Edited the question Mikhail..Can you please help? Thanks a lot for the great help!

Comment: I did many attempts for both the logics, I just wanted to understand how it works with different sets of data as i am confused. I know, this is a question/answer forum, i mentioned the word help as you helped me with understanding through hands-on. Anyways, thanks!

Comment: Can any other person help me with the understanding? I literally spent around 5 hours doing a workaround with different sets of data and that's why i was able to check all of a sudden with different set, but wasn't able to figure out as i am new to bigquery.