# converting multiple comma separated columns into rows in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table in below format,

```
ID    TYPE    VAL        VAL_NO
---   ----    -------    ------
1      5,6    100,200     1,2
2      7,8    400,500     4,5
```

I want the output to be as below,
Expected output:-

```
ID    TYPE    VAL        VAL_NO
---   ----    -------    ------
1      5      100        1
1      6      200        2
2      7      400        4
2      8      500        5
```

I have reposted the question as there is extra column, previously i checked for 2 columns, but now with more than 2 columns, i am facing lot of issues like duplicates etc.

Can someone please help me with this? Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/78061765/5221944